# IP datagram route through a network utilizing ARP

Tags: ip, arp, mac

[image]

Suppose I want to send an IP datagram from node D to node C . Each step I also want to list the MAC addresses of the source and the destination , as well as the source and the destination of the IP datagram .

As a newcomer in networking and in efforts to understand how this would look like , I have came up with a solution which I would like you to criticize and give me pointers to further my knowledge.

Step 1 :

Ethernet(MAC) source : FD-0B-1F-63-32-88  ( MAC of D )
IP source : 128.119.109.251 ( IP of D )

Step 2 :

Ethernet(MAC) destination :FA-C3-3B-23-12-56 ( MAC of inner router)
IP destination : 128.119.109.13 ( IP of C )

Step 3 :

Ethernet(MAC) source : FA-C3-3B-23-12-56 ( MAC of inner router)
IP source : 128.119.109.251 ( IP of D )

Step 4 :

Ethernet(MAC) destination : C4-E6-48-38-CE-AF ( MAC of C )
IP destination : 128.119.109.13 ( IP of C )

Is my way of thinking correct in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't say where your "steps" are, but generally, you're not right.  IP addresses do not change as the packet moves from hop to hop.  Only MAC addresses change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not correct. C and D share a common L2 segment (=broadcast domain) since they're connected by switches. Assuming their network prefixes are /24 (255.255.255.0 mask) they also share a common IP network (subnet).

So,

1. D resolves C's IP to C's MAC address (via ARP for IPv4), if it doesn't already know.
2. D encapsulates the IP packet in a frame addressed to that destination MAC.
3. D sends the frame.
4. The frame is forwarded upwards by the lower right-hand switch.
5. The frame is forwarded towards C by the upper right-hand switch.
6. The frame arrives at C.
7. C decapsulates the original IP packet.

Neither IP addresses nor MAC addresses change in any way on that path. Nothing else in the diagram is required or used for D-to-C traffic.